# Moving decimal without rounding

Tags: python

I'm subtracting time and converting datetime into a string using `.get_seconds()` function.

```
diff = end_date - start_date
seconds = diff.total_seconds()
months = seconds / 2628000
years = months / 12
```

When I print `years`, the number comes out to `0.830136986301`

I was looking at the formatting option in Python

```
format(years, '.0f')
```

But this rounds it up to `1`. Is there anyway I can just "cut" the decimal off without it rounding?

Comment: Is `Math.floor()` what you want?

Comment: Yes! That's what I was looking for :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
format(math.floor(number), '.0f')
```

Answer (score 1):

*Is there anyway I can just "cut" the decimal off without it rounding?*

That is **by definition not possible**, as "cutting the decimal off" implies rounding down. So, no, you cannot. You can, however, manipulate the way in which a number gets rounded!

From what I understand of your question, you could cast to an `int` to get the desired result (this is similar to rounding down), like so:

```
>>>print(int(years))
0
```

Comment: "rounding" without a qualifier means rounding to the nearest integer. That's what he's asking how to avoid.

Comment: @Barmar how is "cutting the decimals" not rounding? That's simply rounding down, if my interpretation of his desired result is correct.

Comment: When he said "without rounding" he meant "without rounding to the nearest integer". The code he wrote rounds up or down, whichever is closer.

Comment: He could have simply written "How do I round down instead of to the nearest integer?"

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called integer division, which is performed with "//".

```
#And then 
years // 12 # Will give you integer without the decimals.
```

Comment: The `//` will perform integer division in both Python 2 and 3, without the future import. The term "true division" refers to the behavior of `/` in Python 3, which is to give a float result.

Comment: Indeed you are right i just use it anyway because i think its nicer the distinction between / and // in python3, i won't change the answer since with your comment it becomes clear.

Comment: The change to `/` has nothing to do with how `//` works and has always worked.

Answer (score 1):

This solution somewhat uses rounding, but you could say:

```
years = math.floor(months / 12)
```

Even better, though, you could truncate the value by saying:

```
years = math.trunc(months / 12)
```

I personally prefer truncate over floor, because truncate and floor handle negative values differently. However, in your case, assuming the value is always positive, both should be suitable solutions that produce the same result. Also, they both rely on the `math` module, so you'll need to include `import math` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers can be negative beware of the floor function.  Here is a comparison of various float to int conversion functions

```
list(map(math.floor, (0.734, -0.734, 0.314, -0.314)))
[0, -1, 0, -1]

list(map(math.ceil, (0.734, -0.734, 0.314, -0.314)))
[1, 0, 1, 0]

list(map(int, (0.734, -0.734, 0.314, -0.314)))
[0, 0, 0, 0]

list(map(round, (0.734, -0.734, 0.314, -0.314)))
[1, -1, 0, 0]

list(map(math.trunc, (0.734, -0.734, 0.314, -0.314)))
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```